# Time complexity of following code with explanation?

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

What is the time complexity of this algorithm, and why?

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

The correct answer is O(n), but I am getting O(nlogn). Can anyone tell me why it's O(n)?

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Please explain where you're stuck and why. This is not a homework service.

Comment: Yes, I did. The issue is Outer loop runs O(logn) and inner loop runs till outer loop. So, it should be O(nlogn). But, I guess it can be reduced to O(n). So, I want to know how mathematically?

Comment: Yes, this should be O(nlogn). But the answer is O(n).So, how is it?

Comment: Can you please show your attempt in the question? I thought I saw you put your attempt in a comment, but then you edited the comment.

Comment: Could you please show your work so far? SO is happy to help when you get *stuck*, not do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration, the inner loop executes `N` times, and then `N/2` times, and then `N/4` times, and so on. This can be expressed as an infinite sum:

```
N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + N/16 + N/32 + ...
```

If you factor out the `N` from each term, you get:

```
N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + ...)
```

The infinite sequence in parentheses converges on the value `2` (more info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)). Therefore, the number of operations can be simplified to:

```
N * 2
```

In terms of Big-O, the asymptotic value is within:

```
O(N)
```

You can check this by observing that the relationship in the output between `N` and `count` is linear: [Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/jORujz)